# Passing DOM element to jQuery custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble on passing DOM element to a function in my custom plugin. As you can see I called `eHeight(this);` in the `$(window).scroll();` function  and I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

then I changed the `this`  to `eHeight(elem);` and this time I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: elem is not defined

How can I pass the selected element to the `eHeight()`?

```js
 (function($) {
      $.fn.boxHeight = function(options) {
    
        var settings = $.extend({
          elemHeight: null
        }, options);
        
    
        var start = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
          var st = $(this).scrollTop();
          if (st > start) {
            eHeight(this);
          } 
          start = st;
        });
    
        function eHeight() {
          var elem = $.trim(elem.attr('id'));
          elem = "#" + elem;
          var theHeight = $(elem).height();
            if ($.isFunction(options.elemHeight)) {
                  options.elemHeight.call();
             }
             options.elemHeight.call();
        }
     
      };
    })(jQuery);
    
    $('#c').boxHeight({
      elemHeight: function() {
        $('#result').html('The Height is: ');
      }
    });
```

```css
div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#c {
  background-color: khaki;
}

#result {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'>A</div>
<div id='b'>B</div>
<div id='c'>C</div>
<div id='d'>D</div>
<div id='e'>E</div>
<div id='f'>F</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: that statement `var elem = $.trim(elem.attr('id'));` makes no sense :)

Comment: Where is `elem` defined? `eHeight` does not expect a parameter.

Comment: @guest271314, as you can see I tried to define it inside the `eHeigh()` function. I also tried defining it on top of the plugin before settings but still getting same error

Comment: Are you expecting `elem` to be element that  plugin chained to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable referencing `this` element within plugin, and parameter expected at `elemHeight`, pass the reference to `elemHeight`. `$.trim()` and call `.call()` calls are not necessary

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.boxHeight = function(options) {
    var elem = this;
    var settings = $.extend({
      elemHeight: null
    }, options);


    var start = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > start) {
        eHeight(elem);
      }
      start = st;
    });

    function eHeight(elem) {
      var theHeight = elem.height();
      if ($.isFunction(options.elemHeight)) {
        options.elemHeight(theHeight);
      }
    }

  };
})(jQuery);

$('#c').boxHeight({
  elemHeight: function(theHeight) {
    $('#result').html('The Height is: ' + theHeight);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#c {
  background-color: khaki;
}

#result {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'>A</div>
<div id='b'>B</div>
<div id='c'>C</div>
<div id='d'>D</div>
<div id='e'>E</div>
<div id='f'>F</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks guest271314 but how do we select the element exactly? I mean I thought we have to select the element by class or attribute and that's why I used the `  var elem = $.trim(elem.attr('id'));` by apparently you just pass the element without any of those attributes!